Data revalidation doesn't work when fetching a route handler in Next.js Server Component
I'm fetching a router handler in Next.js server component using the next.revalidate property, and it doesn't revalidate in production even after I refresh the page several seconds later. However, it works in the local environment.
You might be wondering why I'm fetching the router handler in server component. The reason is that I want to implement ISR.
My actual logic involves fetching data from DynamoDB using the aws-sdk. My DB is updated once an hour by a cron job. Since the data is partially dynamic, that's why I want to use ISR.
So I implemented the logic in the route handler and tried to fetch it in server component with the next.revalidate property.
I've created a simple reproduction:
export default async function Home() {
  const res1 = await fetch(process.env.API_BASE_URL + "/todo", {
    next: {
      revalidate: 2,
    },
  });
  const { id: id1 } = await res1.json();

  const res2 = await fetch(
    `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${getRandomInt(1, 200)}`,
    {
      next: {
        revalidate: 2,
      },
    }
  );
  const { id: id2 } = await res2.json();

  return (
    <main>
      <h1>Fetch Route Handler</h1>
      <span>{id1}</span>

      <h1>Fetch External URL</h1>
      <span>{id2}</span>
    </main>
  );
}

The /todo API works the same as the second logic in the code above.
id1 is not revalidated, but id2 is revalidated when I refresh the page.
process.env.API_BASE_URL is the URL of the deployed site + "/api", FYI.
Does anyone know why?
My Next.js is latest version and I deployed on Vercel.

You can check it on the deployed site: https://isr-reproduction.vercel.app/
Reproduction repo: https://github.com/unhyif/ISR-reproduction

Thank you.

I found this: Next.js | Request Memoization which seems to explain your issue

@clxrity Hi, I realized it was because the result from router handler was statically built as well. It was related to Data Cache section on the page you provided. Thank you for your help.
